# Autohokey Script not retriving result correctly from powershell clipboard

Tags: powershell, autohotkey

I wrote this simple Autohotkey script to retrieve the AD user name from the given description given then see if the user ID is locked or not.

Half of the script working fine, except the part where the 2nd Powershell command :

```
Ver="%Ver%"
Runwait, PowerShell.exe -Command (Get-Aduser %Ver% -Properties LockedOut).LockedOut | clip,,hide
Result=%clipboard%
```

this part above, only work if its alone on another script. for some reason, the clipboard on the first powershell command which is retrieve the UserName ( SamAccountName), is not overwritten by the value of the 2nd powershell command. that cause the previous Clipboard value stuck and so the 2nd command fail as its should shows "True or False" instead of the previous value of the UserName.

the full script below. can anyone advice what am missing here?

```
    ShowMainGui:
 {

 ;## Read cach file for history and if empty clear it value
IniRead, readfile, %A_MyDocuments%\Luser.ini, main, Key


If (readfile = "ERROR")
{
readfile =
}
Else
{

} 



 InputBox, UserInput, Enter CorpNO, Please enter CorpNO:, , 250, 150, 700,340 , , , %readfile%

if ErrorLevel {
    exit
    }
else
 {

  ;##log Corp to Logfile first
 IniWrite, %userinput%, %A_MyDocuments%\Luser.ini, main, Key

 ;;from Description to username
 Runwait, PowerShell.exe -Command "Get-AdUser -Filter {(description -like '%UserInput%')} | foreach { $_.SamAccountName } | clip",, hide


Ver =%clipboard%

 StringReplace , Ver, Ver, %A_Space%,,All

Msgbox, 262144, The user name is ,%Ver%




 ;;; check if the user ID is Locked or not. False or True should be the result

 Ver:="%Ver%"

Runwait, PowerShell.exe -Command (Get-Aduser %Ver% -Properties LockedOut).LockedOut | clip,,hide
Result=%clipboard%
Msgbox, 262144, False or true,%Result%

 ;;; end of checking



 If InStr(Result, "False") {
    Msgbox, 262144, Attention, your account is not locked!
    Goto, ShowMainGui
}

 MsgBox 4,, Account Locked! Do you want to Unlock it?
IfMsgBox Yes
{

 Run, PowerShell.exe -Command "Unlock-ADAccount -Identity %Ver%",, hide
 MsgBox 4,, Account is UnLocked!

}

IfMsgBox no
{
 Goto, ShowMainGui

}





}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all!

I figured it out myself just now. all i have to do is linking the whole command in one line. if PowerShell is allowing multiple commands in one line, then why its not the Autohotkey ;)

Don't know why i cant overwrite the value of the Clipboard yet and i will dig more to find out why, but here is both lines of commands in one line. work like a charm:

```
Runwait, PowerShell.exe -Command "$qaz = Get-AdUser -Filter {(description -like '%ver%')} | foreach { $_.SamAccountName }"; "Get-ADUser $qaz -Properties LockedOut | foreach { $_.Lockedout } | clip",, hide
```